# Regular expression to avoid Spaces

Tags: ruby, regex

I have one problem with the expression below. I am trying to do URL validation using regular expression below:

```
    ^http(s?):\/\/(\w+\.)?[\w%\-\.$,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]+\.[\w\.$,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]+|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}+\/$
```

The expression above allows IP address as well as `http/https:`. It accepts spaces in between url. (http://example.com). How do I restrict spaces in the expression above?

Comment: Can you give an example of something that matches that should not?

Comment: What do you mean by that it accepts spaces in between url as in `http://example.com`? I see no spaces there.

Comment: hello sawa, sorry I forgot to add space in between url e.g(www.goog     le.co m)

Comment: That doesn't match your regular expression: http://www.rubular.com/r/BqaYjqbk5n

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in a `$` (to require a line end) into your first condition:

```
^http(s?):\/\/(\w+\.)?[\w%\-\.$,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]+\.[\w\.$,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]+$|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}+\/$
   ------Add in $ here---------------------------------------------------------^
```

[Example](http://www.rubular.com/r/ktgfBTWdtp)

With that said, there's already built-in modules that are *very good* at parsing and validating URIs.  I suggest using one of those.

Comment: Mike can you please suggest me, which special characters allowed in domain. for e.g (www.ex$am%ple.com).

Comment: I want to restrict special characters in domain part.

Comment: You can use letters (abc), numbers (123) and hyphens (-).  Though domains can't begin or end with a hyphen.  Now you see why people are suggesting using an *existing* module that already has all this knowledge built in.

Comment: @prasad_g I will say again, a final time, that you're doing this wrong, and your regex is broken. **Don't use a regex to do this**. The [actual regex to validate a URL is over 5000 characters long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url). You have *no hope* of doing this correctly, so don't do it. Use `URI` and get on with your life.

Comment: I agree 100% with @meagar.

Comment: Hey meagar yesterday I don't have time to fix. But I tried today and works. Thanks for suggestion and help. Also thanks to Mike.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. This isn't a suitable use of Regular Expressions, and you will *never* get it right for all possible URLs. Use the [URI module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) to actually parse the URL, and catch the exception it will raise if you feed it an invalid URL.

```
require 'URI'

URI("http://google.com") # => #<URI::HTTP:0x007fb08500d3a8 URL:http://google.com>
URI("http://a b") # URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://a b
```

Comment: Okey Thanks meagar. I will try by URI module.